# expo-mediaLibrary, but there is a problem when the user's permission is select photos

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo

We are developing with EXPO + TypeScript.

We developed a screen component called Gallery because we needed a screen where users could select photos.

The problem here is that if the user selects "select photos" and "select more photos" as shown in the picture below, the selected photos are not loaded. It will be loaded when you enter the gallery screen component again.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jz2uO.png)

Any workaround?

code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  FlatList,
  Image,
  ActivityIndicator,
  Dimensions,
  Pressable,
  Text,
  AppState,
  Linking,
} from 'react-native';
import * as MediaLibrary from 'expo-media-library';
import useDidUpdate from '../hooks/useDidUpdate';

import Header from '../components/ui/Header';
import Color from '../constants/color';
import TYPOS from '../components/ui/typo';
import Camera from '../components/ui/icons/Camera';
import { StackScreenProps } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { RootStackParamList } from '../types/navigation';
import { useRecoilState } from 'recoil';
import { LoadingState } from '../store/atoms';

export type GalleryScreenProps = StackScreenProps<
  RootStackParamList,
  'Gallery'
>;

const Gallery = ({ navigation, route }: GalleryScreenProps) => {
  const [photos, setPhotos] = useState<MediaLibrary.Asset[]>([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useRecoilState(LoadingState);
  const [hasNextPage, setHasNextPage] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [endCursor, setEndCursor] = useState<string | undefined>(undefined);

  const [selectedPhtos, setSelectedPhtos] = useState<MediaLibrary.Asset[]>([]);

  const { limit, callback } = route.params;

  const requestMediaLibraryPermissions = async () => {
    const { status } = await MediaLibrary.requestPermissionsAsync();

    if (status !== 'granted') {
      console.log('Media library permission denied');
      Linking.openSettings();
      return;
    }

    fetchPhotos();
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    requestMediaLibraryPermissions();
  }, []);

  useDidUpdate(() => {
    if (!photos.length) {
      fetchPhotos();
    }
  }, [photos]);

  const initPhotos = () => {
    setPhotos([]);
  };

  const fetchPhotos = async (cursor?: string | undefined) => {
    setIsLoading(true);

    try {
      const {
        assets,
        endCursor: newEndCursor,
        hasNextPage,
      } = await MediaLibrary.getAssetsAsync({
        mediaType: MediaLibrary.MediaType.photo,
        first: 20,
        after: cursor,
      });

      setPhotos((prevPhotos) => [...prevPhotos, ...assets]);
      setEndCursor(newEndCursor);
      setHasNextPage(hasNextPage);
      setIsLoading(false);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error fetching photos:', error);
    }
  };

  const renderPhotoItem: React.FC<{ item: MediaLibrary.Asset }> = ({
    item,
  }) => {
    const windowWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;
    const numColumns = 3;
    const itemWidth = windowWidth / numColumns;
    const selectedIndex = [...selectedPhtos].findIndex(
      ({ id }) => item.id === id
    );
    const isSelected = selectedIndex !== -1;

    return (
      <Pressable
        style={{ width: itemWidth, aspectRatio: 1, position: 'relative' }}
        onPress={() => {
          if (isSelected) {
            const clone = [...selectedPhtos];
            clone.splice(selectedIndex, 1);
            setSelectedPhtos(clone);
          } else {
            if (selectedPhtos.length < limit) {
              const clone = [...selectedPhtos];
              clone.push(item);
              setSelectedPhtos(clone);
            }
          }
        }}
      >
        <View
          style={{
            position: 'absolute',
            width: 16,
            height: 16,
            zIndex: 1,
            elevation: 1,
            borderRadius: 16,
            backgroundColor: isSelected ? Color.primary700 : Color.white,
            borderColor: isSelected ? Color.primary700 : Color.neutral3,
            borderWidth: 1,
            right: 12,
            top: 12,
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
          }}
        >
          {isSelected && (
            <Text style={[TYPOS.body3, { color: Color.white }]}>
              {selectedIndex + 1}
            </Text>
          )}
        </View>
        <Image
          source={{ uri: item.uri }}
          style={{ flex: 1, resizeMode: 'cover' }}
        />
      </Pressable>
    );
  };

  const renderCameraButton = () => (
    <Pressable
      onPress={handleTakePhoto}
      style={{
        width: itemWidth,
        aspectRatio: 1,
        backgroundColor: Color.white,
        flexDirection: 'column',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
      }}
    >
      <Camera size={32} />
      <Text style={[TYPOS.body3, { color: Color.black }]}>move Camera</Text>
    </Pressable>
  );

  const onCompleteHandler = () => {
    callback([...selectedPhtos]);
    navigation.goBack();
  };

  const handleEndReached = () => {
    if (hasNextPage) {
      fetchPhotos(endCursor);
    }
  };

  const handleTakePhoto = () => {
    navigation.navigate('Camera', { callback: initPhotos });
  };

  const windowWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;
  const numColumns = 3;
  const itemWidth = windowWidth / numColumns;

  return (
    <>
      <Header
        title="images"
        rightContent={
          <Pressable onPress={onCompleteHandler}>
            <Text
              style={[
                TYPOS.small,
                {
                  color:
                    selectedPhtos.length > 0
                      ? Color.primary900
                      : Color.neutral2,
                },
              ]}
            >
              done
            </Text>
          </Pressable>
        }
      />
      <FlatList
        data={[null, ...photos]}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        numColumns={numColumns}
        renderItem={({ item, index }) =>
          item
            ? renderPhotoItem({ item })
            : index === 0
            ? renderCameraButton()
            : null
        }
        onEndReached={handleEndReached}
        onEndReachedThreshold={0.1}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default Gallery;
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this change anything? Usig the library expo-image-picker instead.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, TouchableOpacity, View, ScrollView, ImageBackground, StyleSheet, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import {
  scale,
  verticalScale,
  moderateScale,
  ScaledSheet,
} from 'react-native-size-matters';
import { MaterialCommunityIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';

const windowWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;

export default function ImportPictures(props) {
    const [image, setImage] = React.useState(null);
    const {colors } = props;

    const pickImage = async () => {
        // No permissions request is necessary for launching the image library
        let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
          mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
          allowsEditing: true,
          aspect: [4, 3],
          quality: 1,
        });
    
        console.log(result);
    
        if (!result.canceled) {
          setImage(result.assets[0].uri);
        }
      };


    return (
        <View style={{justifyContent: 'center', alignItems:'center'}}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={pickImage}>  
                <MaterialCommunityIcons
                    name="camera-plus"
                    size={70}
                    color={'grey'}
                />
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <View style={{width: scale(200), top: scale(10),}}>
                <Text style={{textAlign: 'center', fontSize: 18,  color: colors.sliderText}}>Import Photos!</Text>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
};
```